# How to save array list of custom objects using gson

Tags: android, json

I have a class called 'user' which has an attribute which is a list of a custom class called 'jobs' i  cast user to json and save in in the file system, now my problem is with jobs i used Gson to save it but i have that error :

**java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT**

Here is user class where i convert it to json using method **userToJson** and  i use a constructor with json object to deserialize it

```
public class User implements Serializable {
private String FirstName;
private String LastName;
private String Email;
private String Phone;
private String Town;
private ArrayList<Job> Jobs;
private Location location;
private Boolean hasBusiness;

public User(){
    Jobs = new ArrayList<>();
}
public User(JSONObject userJson) throws JSONException {
    FirstName = userJson.getString(Constants.FILE_FIRST_NAME);
    LastName = userJson.getString(Constants.FILE_LAST_NAME);
    Email = userJson.getString(Constants.FILE_EMAIL);
    Phone = userJson.getString(Constants.FILE_PHONE);
    Town = userJson.getString(Constants.FILE_TOWN);
    String locationJSON = userJson.getString(Constants.FILE_LOCATION);
    location = new Gson().fromJson(locationJSON,Location.class);
    hasBusiness = userJson.getBoolean(Constants.FILE_HAS_BUSINESS);

    Type type = new TypeToken<List<Job>>(){}.getType();
    String jobJson= userJson.get(Constants.FILE_JOBS).toString();
    Jobs = new Gson().fromJson(jobJson,type);


}

public String getFirstName() {
    return FirstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    FirstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return LastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    LastName = lastName;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return Email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    Email = email;
}

public String getPhone() {
    return Phone;
}

public void setPhone(String phone) {
    Phone = phone;
}

public String getTown() {
    return Town;
}

public void setTown(String town) {
    Town = town;
}

public Location getLocation() {
    return location;
}

public void setLocation(Location location) {
    this.location = location;
}

public void setHasBusiness(Boolean hasBusiness) {
    this.hasBusiness = hasBusiness;
}

public Boolean getHasBusiness() {
    return hasBusiness;
}

public ArrayList<Job> getJobs() {
    return Jobs;
}

public void setJobs(ArrayList<Job> jobs) {
    Jobs = jobs;
}

public JSONObject userToJson() throws JSONException{
    JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();
    jo.put(Constants.FILE_FIRST_NAME,this.FirstName);
    jo.put(Constants.FILE_LAST_NAME,this.LastName);
    jo.put(Constants.FILE_TOWN,this.Town);
    jo.put(Constants.FILE_PHONE,this.Phone);
    jo.put(Constants.FILE_EMAIL,this.Email);
    jo.put(Constants.FILE_LOCATION,new Gson().toJson(location));
    jo.put(Constants.FILE_HAS_BUSINESS,hasBusiness);
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
    for(Job j : this.Jobs){
        jsonArray.put(j);
    }
    Log.d("JobsJobs",new Gson().toJson(jsonArray));
    jo.put(Constants.FILE_JOBS,new Gson().toJson(jsonArray));
    return jo;
}
```

}

Now the jobs string is as follows (it's empty) but it's about the structure i think

{"values":[]}

Answer (score 0):

This is beacause you are getting the list of jobs inside a json object, under the variable `values`

So to attain the the list of jobs you need to modify your code as follows

Jobs = new Gson().fromJson(jobJson,type).getJSONArray("values");

Comment: getJSONArray doesn't exist :D but i got your point, thanks

Comment: Yeah my bad, Jsons have multiple libraries and ways to deal with, bit of trial error stuff